# Is it possible to get all the projects and subprojects using TFS API

Tags: tfs, c#-4.0

I am working on TFS API. I am trying to get the entire list of projects, subprojects, files from TFS.
Could someone guide me regarding it.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = teamFoundationserver.TfsTeamProjectCollection;
ProjectCollection projCollect = (ProjectCollection) teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ProjectCollection));
```

The above code just shows the first level from TFS. How Can I go further deep into TFS tree.
I want the entire list of projects, and **solutions** under each project.

Thanks,
SV

Comment: I can already get the project collections, but there are projects under each project collection and beneath that solutions. It is the solution I'm after. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  Once you have the tree, you can walk the tree to iterate through all your solutions.  We do this for several types of auditing processes.

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as a "subproject."  What it sounds like you want to do is get a listing of all subfolders / files under each project.

To do that, iterate through each of your projects, and do a `GetItems` on each.  Here's some code:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://sw100429:8080"));

ProjectCollection projCollect = (ProjectCollection)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ProjectCollection));

VersionControlServer vcs = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

// This approach lets you get the list of files for each team project individually.

foreach (TeamProject tp in projCollect)
{
    string path = string.Format("$/{0}", tp.Name);
    var filesAndFolders = vcs.GetItems(path, RecursionType.Full);
}


// However, this approach is a bit more succinct - instead
// of getting them for each team project, just start at "$/" and work your way down

var allFilesAndFolders = vcs.GetItems("$/", RecursionType.Full);
```

Comment: Hi, again, Robaticus - as I said up above - I am not after the folders, but the solutions under each project. Hmm, even the files and folders would offer a new view. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using your q&a (thanks) I was able to put this sample together after a lot of trial and error. It goes a step further to show how to map the local paths too. I hope this saves some readers some head aches.

This example was put together in a form in VS 2015 and uses the following assembly references (that were also tricky to track down)

All located in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\vl45o2it.tph** on my machine.

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll
```

**Apologies if my terminology is out in places. I don't mind if you edit any of this.**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace Tfs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Uri tfsUri = new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs");
            string repositoryName = "yourrepository";
            string projectPath = "$/project/path/path/path";

            Uri repositoryUri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tfsUri.AbsoluteUri, repositoryName));

            TfsConfigurationServer tfscs = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

            //get the repository
            CatalogNode repository = tfscs.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new Guid[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None)
                .FirstOrDefault(a => string.Compare(a.Resource.DisplayName, repositoryName, true) == 0);

            //open in the project collection
            TfsTeamProjectCollection pc = tfscs.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Guid(repository.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]));

            //tfs project file structure access
            VersionControlServer vcs = pc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            WorkspaceInfo wsi = Workstation.Current.GetAllLocalWorkspaceInfo().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ServerUri == repositoryUri);

            //user functionality (checkin, localpaths etc)
            Workspace ws = wsi.GetWorkspace(pc);

            //get the file structure
            ItemSet items = vcs.GetItems(projectPath, RecursionType.Full);

            foreach (Item i in items.Items)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}) - {2} - {3}", i.ServerItem,
                                                                       i.ContentLength.ToString(),
                                                                       i.ItemType.ToString(),
                                                                       ws.GetLocalItemForServerItem(i.ServerItem)));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: None of the suggestions provided seem to have a way to get at solutions under projects. I'll follow up on your suggestion of VersionControlServer and see if that helps. Our situation is a project collection holding multiple projects, each of which holds one or more solutions.

Comment: And each solution holds one or more Visual Studio projects (rather than TFS projects)