# From TFS I need the code to retrieve the project name from specific collection by passing collection name as parameter using MVC Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs

```
    public ActionResult Connect()
    {
            List<string> Collected = new List<string>(10);
            Uri configurationServerUri = new Uri("xxxxxxtfsurl");
            TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =

            TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer
            (configurationServerUri);

            ITeamProjectCollectionService tpcService = 
            configurationServer.GetService<ITeamProjectCollectionService>();

            foreach (TeamProjectCollection tpc in 
             tpcService.GetCollections())
             {
                 Collected.Add(tpc.Name);
             }
             ViewBag.List = Collected;



             return PartialView();

       }
```

I retrieved the collection using controller in MVC but can any one help me to retrieve the projects from specific collection

Comment: are you asking about the TFS collection's data structure, or something to do with how to use that in MVC specifically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323279/is-it-possible-to-get-all-the-projects-and-subprojects-using-tfs-api might be a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve the team projects from specific collection, then you can use below code sample:

Install Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/).

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string collection = @"http://ictfs2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(collection));
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
        VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        TeamProject[] teamProjects = vcs.GetAllTeamProjects(true);

        foreach (TeamProject proj in teamProjects)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Team Project: {0}", proj.Name));
        }
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you want to retrieve all the collections and their team projects, then you can try below code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace GetProjectList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Connect to Team Foundation Server
            //     Server is the name of the server that is running the application tier for Team Foundation.
            //     Port is the port that Team Foundation uses. The default port is 8080.
            //     VDir is the virtual path to the Team Foundation application. The default path is tfs.
            Uri tfsUri = (args.Length < 1) ?
                new Uri("http://ictfs2015:8080/tfs") : new Uri(args[0]);

            TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
                TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

            // Get the catalog of team project collections
            ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

            // List the team project collections
            foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
            {
                // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
                Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
                TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

                // Print the name of the team project collection
                Console.WriteLine("Collection: " + teamProjectCollection.Name);

                // Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
                ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(
                    new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
                    false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

                // List the team projects in the collection
                foreach (CatalogNode projectNode in projectNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
                }
            }
            // Display the project list on cosole window
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dhanaprasad Have you resolved the issue? any update?